# Creating a responsive background video with material-ui breakpoint down not working

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, gatsby

I would like to create a responsive background video in my react application using material-ui but it seems my understanding of material-ui breakpoints needs some help. My first attempt was doing something like:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) =>
  createStyles({
    root: {
      display: 'inline-block',
      position: 'fixed',
      top: '0',
      right: '0',
      bottom: '0',
      left: '0',
      overflow: 'hidden',
      zIndex: -100,
      padding: theme.spacing(1),
      [theme.breakpoints.down('lg')]: {
        background: 'url("./assets/img/MichaelPR.jpg") center center / cover no-repeat'
      },
    },
    video: {
      position: 'absolute',
      top: '50%',
      left: '50%',
      width: 'auto',
      height: 'auto',
      minHeight: '100%',
      WebkitTransform: 'translate(-50%, -50%)',
      MozTransform: 'translate(-50%, -50%)',
      MsTransform: 'translate(-50%, -50%)',
      transform: 'translate(-50%, -50%)',
      display: 'inline-block',
      [theme.breakpoints.down('lg')]: {
        display: 'none',
      },
    }
  })
);

export default () => {
  const styles = useStyles();
    return (
            <div className={styles.root}>
                <video
                    autoPlay
                    muted
                    loop
                    className={styles.video}
                >
                    <source src='./assets/vid/MichaelPR.mp4' type='video/mp4' />
                    Your device does not support playing 'video/mp4' videos
                </video>
            </div>
    )
}
```

The idea here is to make the video stop displaying and cause the background of the parent div to be a static image for all devices which have a screen size of less than 'lg'. But this is now what happens. What I see is the video is NEVER displayed no matter what the screen size. If I change the breakpoint from 'down' to 'up'. I seems to work as expected but not what is desired. I get a static image for the background and the video display is stopped. So my question is how do I get the desired effect for screen sizes BELOW 'lg'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make it static on all devices less than lg you would want to use theme.breakpoints.down('md') as down is inclusive of the breakpoint you enter.